# Python: strip a wildcard word

Tags: python, regex, string, wildcard

I have strings with words separated by points. 
Example:

```
string1 = 'one.two.three.four.five.six.eight' 
string2 = 'one.two.hello.four.five.six.seven'
```

How do I use this string in a python method, assigning one word as wildcard (because in this case for example the third word varies). I am thinking of regular expressions, but do not know if the approach like I have it in mind is possible in python.
For example:

```
string1.lstrip("one.two.[wildcard].four.")
```

or

```
string2.lstrip("one.two.'/.*/'.four.")
```

(I know that I can extract this by `split('.')[-3:]`, but I am looking for a general way, lstrip is just an example)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use [`re.sub(pattern, '', original_string)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to remove matching part from *original_string*:

```
>>> import re
>>> string1 = 'one.two.three.four.five.six.eight'
>>> string2 = 'one.two.hello.four.five.six.seven'
>>> re.sub(r'^one\.two\.\w+\.four', '', string1)
'.five.six.eight'
>>> re.sub(r'^one\.two\.\w+\.four', '', string2)
'.five.six.seven'
```

BTW, you are misunderstanding [`str.lstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.lstrip):

```
>>> 'abcddcbaabcd'.lstrip('abcd')
''
```

[`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.replace) is more appropriate (of course, *re.sub*, too):

```
>>> 'abcddcbaabcd'.replace('abcd', '')
'dcba'
>>> 'abcddcbaabcd'.replace('abcd', '', 1)
'dcbaabcd'
```

Comment: Thank you! And to your "BTW": Is there a possibility to strip only the "abcd" that are ordered in the right way? or is this a case for regex only?

Comment: @aldorado, `'abcddcbaabcd'.replace('abcd', '', 1)`. `1` means replace only once.

Comment: @aldorado, I added another code that show sample usage of `str.replace`.